# Analytics API shortcuts

Tags: google-analytics-api

Regarding Google Analytics API: Is it possible to consume data from defined shortcuts in GA?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't get data directly from a Shortcut, unfortunately. However, you can definitely get the data - you just have to build a query that gets the same info as the shortcut.

Check out the API Explorer if you haven't before: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/. This is a good way to quickly learn the capabilities of the Core Reporting API v3. It basically comes down to a date range, metrics, dimensions, filters, segments, and sorting.